# Python - How to call a function created into a different file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, callback

I'm pretty new in Python. I'm trying to develop a GUI using a drag and drop designer called PAGE (http://page.sourceforge.net/html/index.html) based on Tkinter.
After having created a new project, I added a button to a window. The following code is autogenerated by PAGE and saved into a file called 'myGui.py':

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

import myGui_support   
    
class Toplevel1:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        ...
        self.StartButton = tk.Button(self.top)       
        self.StartButton.configure(command=myGui_support.StartButton_Callback)        
        ...

    def start_up():
        myGui_support.main()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        myGui_support.main()
```

PAGE creates also a second file called 'myGui_support.py', in which after some import statements, the following code is included:

```
import myGui

def main(*args):
    '''Main entry point for the application.'''
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW' , root.destroy)
    # Creates a toplevel widget.
    global _top1, _w1
    _top1 = root
    _w1 = myGui.Toplevel1(_top1)
    root.mainloop()    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myGui.start_up()
    

def StartButton_CallBack():
    _w1.DebugLabel["text"] = 'START BUTTON PRESSED'

def StopButton_CallBack():
    _w1.DebugLabel["text"] = 'STOP BUTTON PRESSED'
```

Once I run the myGui in Spyder, an Attribute error occurres:

*AttributeError: module 'myGui_support' has no attribute 'StartButton_Callback'*

How can it be possible? I already defined the callback function into the 'myGui_support.py'. Any suggestions?

Comment: Typo: `myGui_support.StartButton_Callback` should be `myGui_support.StartButton_CallBack` (big B in CallBack).

Comment: Ohhh thank you very much...I was getting crazy!